# Reading amount of tracks from an audio CD?

Tags: python, audio-cd

I'm writing a little script to analyze audio CDs. I'm specifically looking for a way to grab the track count from the CD, either from a shell-script or from Python. Is there an easy way to do this?

<sub>On an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative.</sub>

Comment: How did you make the text "on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### cdparanoia

You can get a list of CD audio tracks using the command line tool, `cdparanoia`.

```
$ cdparanoia -sQ
```

#### Example

```
$ cdparanoia -sQ
cdparanoia III release 10.2 (September 11, 2008)


Table of contents (audio tracks only):
track        length               begin        copy pre ch
===========================================================
  1.    19497 [04:19.72]        0 [00:00.00]    OK   no  2
  2.    20253 [04:30.03]    19497 [04:19.72]    OK   no  2
  3.    29250 [06:30.00]    39750 [08:50.00]    OK   no  2
  4.    34263 [07:36.63]    69000 [15:20.00]    OK   no  2
  5.    28804 [06:24.04]   103263 [22:56.63]    OK   no  2
  6.    21582 [04:47.57]   132067 [29:20.67]    OK   no  2
  7.    33270 [07:23.45]   153649 [34:08.49]    OK   no  2
  8.    29919 [06:38.69]   186919 [41:32.19]    OK   no  2
  9.    29564 [06:34.14]   216838 [48:11.13]    OK   no  2
 10.    18993 [04:13.18]   246402 [54:45.27]    OK   no  2
 11.    35368 [07:51.43]   265395 [58:58.45]    OK   no  2
TOTAL  300763 [66:50.13]    (audio only)
```

You can count the number of lines that contain the string "OK" or that start with a number, for e.g. `1.`.

```
$ cdparanoia -sQ |& grep OK | wc -l
11

-or-

$ cdparanoia -sQ |& grep -P "^\s+\d+\." | wc -l
11
```

#### cdda2wav

You can also use this command line tool, `cdda2wav`.

```
$ cdda2wav -J -D /dev/cdrom
```

#### Example

```
$ cdda2wav -J -D /dev/cdrom
Type: ROM, Vendor 'Optiarc ' Model 'DVD RW AD-7930H ' Revision '1.D1' MMC+CDDA
569344 bytes buffer memory requested, 4 buffers, 55 sectors
#icedax version 1.1.11, real time sched., soundcard, libparanoia support
AUDIOtrack pre-emphasis  copy-permitted tracktype channels
      1-11           no             yes     audio    2
Table of Contents: total tracks:11, (total time 66:50.13)
  1.( 4:19.72),  2.( 4:30.03),  3.( 6:30.00),  4.( 7:36.63),  5.( 6:24.04),
  6.( 4:47.57),  7.( 7:23.45),  8.( 6:38.69),  9.( 6:34.14), 10.( 4:13.18),
 11.( 7:51.43)

Table of Contents: starting sectors
  1.(       0),  2.(   19497),  3.(   39750),  4.(   69000),  5.(  103263),
  6.(  132067),  7.(  153649),  8.(  186919),  9.(  216838), 10.(  246402),
 11.(  265395), lead-out(  300763)
CDINDEX discid: gteZIAUq3lgZlEmNg_HnbWL6cJc-
CDDB discid: 0x950faa0b
CD-Text: detected
CD-Extra: not detected
Album title: 'Hour of the Olympics' [from Mary Pope Osborne]
Track  1: 'Viking Ships at Sunrise Ch 3'
Track  2: 'Viking Ships at Sunrise Ch 4'
Track  3: 'Viking Ships at Sunrise Ch 5-6'
Track  4: 'Viking Ships at Sunrise Ch 7-8'
Track  5: 'Viking Ships at Sunrise Ch 9-10'
Track  6: 'Hour of the Olympics Ch 1'
Track  7: 'Hour of the Olympics Ch 2-3'
Track  8: 'Hour of the Olympics Ch 4-5'
Track  9: 'Hour of the Olympics Ch 6-8'
Track 10: 'Hour of the Olympics Ch 9'
Track 11: 'Hour of the Olympics Ch 10'
No media catalog number present.
scanning for ISRCs: 11 ...
index scan: 11...
```

Again you can enlist the help of `grep` to get the number of tracks:

```
# traditional way to parse output
$ cdda2wav -J -D /dev/cdrom |& grep index | sed 's#.*: \(.*\)...#\1#g'
11

# use grep's PCRE capability
$ cdda2wav -J -D /dev/cdrom |& grep -Po '(?<=index scan: )\d+' | tail -1
11
```

#### References

- [HowTo: Linux Rip and Encode Audio CDs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-ripping-and-encoding-audio-files/)

Comment: Grepping on `OK` won't always work. I once found the `copy` column in the TOC to contain also `no`.

Answer (score 1):

[cd-discid](https://github.com/taem/cd-discid) returns the number of tracks, among other CDDB information.

```
$ cd-discid
30087b04 4 150 78547 92953 112181 2173
         ^
         number of tracks
```

To get just the number of tracks:

```
$ tracktotal=$(cd-discid); tracktotal="${tracktotal#* }"; tracktotal="${tracktotal%% *}"; echo $tracktotal
```