# Questions regarding mounting CD-ROM on linux

Tags: debian, mount, dvd

I am trying to mount the dvd+rw drives in my Debian 7 PC. There are two drives and I can see that these exist in `/dev`:

```
$ ls -la /dev/dvd*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Oct 26 07:47 dvd -> sr1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Oct 26 12:41 dvd1 -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Oct 26 07:47 dvdrw -> sr1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Oct 26 12:41 dvdrw1 -> sr0
```

The following lines exist in my `/etc/fstab` file and were not put there by me:

```
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto 0 0
/dev/sr1 /media/cdrom1 udf,iso9660 user,noauto 0 0
```

Nobody else has used this PC - I only recently installed debian7 and so, I assume that the installation process created these mount-points automatically.

If I run `sudo mount -a` the drives do not mount, though:

```
$ mount | grep cd
# no results returned
$ df | grep cd
# no results returned
```

I tried changing `/etc/fsab` to:

```
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0 defaults 0 0
/dev/sr1 /media/cdrom1 defaults 0 0
```

But there were still no results from `mount` or `df`. As suggested by [jordanm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13796/jordanm), i have tried to mount one of the drives manually:

```
$ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o defaults /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

Comment: You will probably find that most of those things are symlinks to each other. Try to mount manually or use your GUI file manager.

Comment: oh you are absolutely right! i have no gui tho. will update the question...

Comment: Is this a data CD or audio CD? You can't mount an audio CD like that.

Comment: its an audio cd. i didn't realise that the type of cd mattered. truth be told i thought i was interfacing with the drive (hardware) rather than a filesystem burnt on the cd

Comment: The mount command can only mount drives that have filesystems on them.

Comment: Best thing to do is to check your filesystem!

Comment: + 1 fore mentioning that audio cds can't be mounted using mount command..

Answer (score 3):

If the CD discs are data disk, then they'll be mounted as you've described, however if they're audio CDs then no they won't get mounted like a traditional drive. Applications that can make use of audio CDs will simply access this media when you refer to it in these tools.

See my answer to this U&L Q&A titled: [Reading amount of tracks from an audio CD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92890/reading-amount-of-tracks-from-an-audio-cd).

#### Example

2 such tools are `cdparanoia` or `cdda2wav`.

```
$ cdparanoia -sQ
cdparanoia III release 10.2 (September 11, 2008)


Table of contents (audio tracks only):
track        length               begin        copy pre ch
===========================================================
  1.    19497 [04:19.72]        0 [00:00.00]    OK   no  2
  2.    20253 [04:30.03]    19497 [04:19.72]    OK   no  2
  3.    29250 [06:30.00]    39750 [08:50.00]    OK   no  2
  4.    34263 [07:36.63]    69000 [15:20.00]    OK   no  2
  5.    28804 [06:24.04]   103263 [22:56.63]    OK   no  2
  6.    21582 [04:47.57]   132067 [29:20.67]    OK   no  2
  7.    33270 [07:23.45]   153649 [34:08.49]    OK   no  2
  8.    29919 [06:38.69]   186919 [41:32.19]    OK   no  2
  9.    29564 [06:34.14]   216838 [48:11.13]    OK   no  2
 10.    18993 [04:13.18]   246402 [54:45.27]    OK   no  2
 11.    35368 [07:51.43]   265395 [58:58.45]    OK   no  2
TOTAL  300763 [66:50.13]    (audio only)
```